# Is there any way to show whole text in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello I want to show whole text in xamarin forms page(without limiting my text).I know there are ways to show multiple lines but I dont want to put a limit to it.I just want to show all text ,no matter it is 2 lines or 5 lines.
Thanks

Comment: Use `Editor` instead of `Entry` then

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Label Text="Long text" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
```

Use **LineBreakMode** Property and set it as **WordWrap**

Answer (score -1):

Set LineBreakMode of Label to NoWrap